# Chained calls may cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, idisposable

In a chain call, there are intermediate products. If there is an intermediate product that inherits from IDisposable, then usually we should use using to make it automatically released. But I ignored this in the chain call and only used one using to release the resource object I ultimately needed. So will this cause a memory leak?

According to my actual test: divide the chain call into multiple lines for execution, and use using to modify all resource objects in it (not just the last one). Comparing the memory usage before and after shows that there is indeed a memory leak. I would like to ask if anyone has encountered this situation. This kind of memory leak seems to be relatively easy to happen.

Comment: Can you show a small code example what you are doing?

Comment: What is the type of those "intermediate products"?

Comment: "This kind of memory leak seems to be relatively easy to happen." Eeeh, yes, it does. And what exactly is your question? When something is diposable, you should dispose it - which is with a `using`-keyword or manually using a `try`/`finally`-block and a call to `Dispose`. Ypu already have yourself the answer.

Comment: "Intermediate products" are objects that require us to manually release memory. Specifically, they refer to classes that inherit IDisposed. Using using to modify it will automatically call dispose() to release memory when its scope ends. Such objects are often called "unmanaged resources", that is, objects that will not be managed by the garbage collector.

Comment: `Dispose()` is NOT generally used to free memory, since memory in C# is a *managed* resource. Generally, `Dispose()` is used to free *unmanaged* resources such as file handles. However, `Dispose()` may also commonly be used to detach event handlers that would otherwise keep the object alive.

Comment: Note that if you have enabled Code Analysis and its [CA2000 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CA2000)%26rd%3Dtrue) you will be warned about failing to call `Dispose()` in the scenario that you describe.

Comment: I'd be very cautious describing this as a "leak"; this isn't a "leak" - it only becomes a "leak" if the memory is never recoverable, for example because a graph is rooted somehow; this is just *memory usage* - albeit with a "we could have disposed some things earlier than GC will finalize them"

Comment: @MarcGravell What you mean is that if this intermediate product has no reference to it, or the reference is eventually broken. So the garbage collector will still recycle it later without causing a real memory leak?

Comment: @GuruStron sr ... Because I am relatively familiar with these two languages and know that they have corresponding things.

Comment: @SomeBody like using clazz x =  MethodA.CallFir().CallSec(); and the fir call returns a class which should be disposed .but i just noticed the sec one which returns x

Comment: @jhchen yes; in particular, note that `Dispose()` **does not** cause GC to happen, so *even if you dispose things properly*: that changes very little about allocations. What *can* be different is if 1: the `Dispose()` recycles things like pooled buffers, making *those* more reusable, reducing *unrelated* allocations, or 2: the `Dispose()` releases some unmanaged resource *more promptly* than GC would allow, again reducing overall system load

Answer (score 2):

###### This kind of memory leak seems to be relatively easy to happen.

Yes, it does, and yes, if you have a `IDisposable` object which controls some unmanaged resources and you will not call `Dispose` on it (manually or via `using`) you will get a memory leak unless you have a [finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers) defined:

> Finalizers (historically referred to as destructors) are used to perform any necessary final clean-up when a class instance is being collected by the garbage collector.

Hence using some fluent API-like calls on such code is dangerous. For example in the following code:

```cs
var result = CreateSomeInstWithUnmanagedResource()
    .TransformTheInstanceWithoutCapture();
```

If `TransformTheInstanceWithoutCapture` does not dispose the incoming instance with unmanaged resources created by `CreateSomeInstWithUnmanagedResource` then the resources will not be disposed.

Though relying on finalizers is not recommended for multiple reasons, for example due to the non-deterministic invocation (you don't know when GC will run) start and prolonged lifetime of the finalized object.

See also:

- [When everything you know is wrong, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/), [part two](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)
- Consider enabling [CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000)

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that Microsoft's Code Analysis will often (although not always) warn about this if the CA2000 warning is enabled.